# How to document options in an INI file with Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, ini

I'd like to document an INI file in my Sphinx documentation. What markup should I use?

Whenever I search the Web I get description of Sphinx configuration file—conf.py.

The [standard domain](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#the-standard-domain) has some tools to document command-line programs and one could use `describe` (`object`) role but as the documentation states "This directive produces the same formatting as the specific ones provided by domains, but does not create index entries or cross-referencing targets".

I need something more specific to describe sections and options and to be able to refer to them.

So having an INI file:

```
[ui]
username = Mike
e-mail = mike@domain.com
```

I would like to be able to use something like this:

```
.. ini:section:: ui

    This section contains setting for use interface 

.. ini:option:: username

    User name
    ...
```

Is there better way to do that than writing my own extension?

Comment: There is duplicated text in the question. It looks like the second occurrence of "So having an INI file:" and the text after it can be removed.

Comment: @mzjn good catch, removed the dupe part.

Comment: Polite suggestion: Would it be worth it (time/effort/etc) to convert your INI file to a `config.py` file?  This way, you can document your config file in the same manner as the rest of your project.  (This is a method we use regularly and provides a means to hyperlink project documentation directly to the associated config entry.)

Comment: @S3DEV But documenting things with Sphinx doesn't necessarily mean they are implemented in Python.

Answer (score 4):

After studying Sphinx and extensions' source code, this is a minimal solution I came up with. Put the snippet into your `conf.py`:

```
from sphinx.application import Sphinx
from sphinx.util.docfields import Field


def setup(app: Sphinx):
    app.add_object_type(
        'confval',
        'confval',
        objname='configuration value',
        indextemplate='pair: %s; configuration value',
        doc_field_types=[
            Field('type', label='Type', has_arg=False, names=('type',)),
            Field('default', label='Default', has_arg=False, names=('default',)),
        ]
    )
```

This adds a pair of directive `.. confval::` and a role `:confval:` that mimic the `.. option::`/`:option:` or `.. envvar::`/`:envvar:` pairs.

#### Example

```
Configuration
-------------

For more verbose output, increase the :confval:`verbose` parameter.
To show the traceback, set :confval:`show_traceback = True <show_traceback>`.

.. confval:: verbose

   :type: integer
   :default: 0

   More verbose output.

.. confval:: show_traceback

   :type: boolean
   :default: ``False``

   Show traceback on errors.


.. confval:: output

   :type: string
   :default: ``-``

   Target path to write the output.
```

renders as

[image]

allowing for nice crossrefs throughout the docs.

Comment: Open issues: I don't know how to reference python types from the `std` domain (e.g. I set `:type: bool` and Sphinx renders a link to https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool etc). Also missing stuff like sections support, will mimic them via Sphinx section headings for now.

Comment: I think the standard library types should auto-resolve if you used intersphinx with the [right mapping](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/3.x/doc/conf.py#L122) and programmatically substitute the [proper role](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#the-python-domain). Sphinx-napoleon does this transparently for its type hint fields. How it resolves types of the package being documented I don't know, or how it looks them up. But I suppose they're put into the same cross-ref type lookup index by intersphinx.